# Vuetify: How do I prevent all expand-transition from happening at once?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a page that consists of multiple cards, each card has a v-expand-transition and I am creating all cards in a v-for loop. The problem is that if I click one v-expand-transition then all of them open. I understand that it is because all of them are connected to the same "show", but I am not sure how to split that up so each one has their own event. My code is here:

```
<template>
<v-container>
    <h1 class="font-weight-medium pa-6">All Labs</h1>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col v-for="card in cards" :key="card.title" :cols="card.flex">
        <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="350">
          <v-img class="white--text align-end" height="200px" :src="card.src" gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)">
            <v-card-title v-text="card.title"></v-card-title>
          </v-img>
        <v-card-subtitle class="pb=0" v-text="card.location"></v-card-subtitle>
        <v-card-text class="text--primary">
          <div v-text="card.hours"></div>
          <div v-text="card.keycardInfo"></div>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color="blue" :href="card.directions" text target="_blank">Directions</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="blue" :to="card.page" text>Learn More</v-btn>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn icon @click="show = !show">
            <v-icon>{{ show ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down'}}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
        <v-expand-transition>
          <div v-show="show">
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-text v-text="card.bottomInfo"></v-card-text>
          </div>
        </v-expand-transition>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

and my script is here:

```
<script>
import App from '../App.vue'

  export default {
  components: { App },
    name: 'Home',
    data: () => ({
      show: false,
      cards: [],
        
    }),
  }
</script>
```

I emptied the cards to avoid cluttering the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that since you are using a single variable to control the state of your component, the action will end up reflecting for everyone. One alternative would be to add a "show" property inside each object in your list, making each object have its own state. Here is an example of how it would look:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       cards: [{
         title: "My title",
         flex: 6,
         src: '#',
         location: '#',
         hours: '13',
         keycardInfo: 'Info',
         directions: '#',
         page: '#',
         to: '#',
         bottomInfo: 'Bottom info',
         show: false,
       },
       {
         title: "My title 2",
         flex: 6,
         src: '#',
         location: '#',
         hours: '13',
         keycardInfo: 'Info 2',
         directions: '#',
         page: '#',
         to: '#',
         bottomInfo: 'Bottom info 2',
         show: false,
       }],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<div id="app">
  <v-container>
    <h1 class="font-weight-medium pa-6">All Labs</h1>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col v-for="card in cards" :key="card.title" :cols="card.flex">
        <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="350">
          <v-img class="white--text align-end" height="200px" :src="card.src" gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)">
            <v-card-title v-text="card.title"></v-card-title>
          </v-img>
        <v-card-subtitle class="pb=0" v-text="card.location"></v-card-subtitle>
        <v-card-text class="text--primary">
          <div v-text="card.hours"></div>
          <div v-text="card.keycardInfo"></div>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color="blue" :href="card.directions" text target="_blank">Directions</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="blue" :to="card.page" text>Learn More</v-btn>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn  @click="card.show = !card.show">
            {{ card.show ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
        <v-expand-transition>
          <div v-show="card.show">
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-text v-text="card.bottomInfo"></v-card-text>
          </div>
        </v-expand-transition>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

As you are using Vuetify, another approach would be to use expansion panels, I'll leave the documentation link below for you to take a look.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#usage